# SQL Server: executing part of a stored procedure that is in one database against all other databases

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am trying to run this procedure in order to select a bunch of results from multiple tables in another databases and put everything into one temp table. I can only use this one stored procedure and can't put it into another database

I tried using this here, but it didn't work and gave me the error

> 'Must declare the scalar variable "@lcsqlcmd"'. @lcsqlcmd

I already declared though any help?

```
EXEC master..sp_MSforeachdb 

IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TempTable
       EXECUTE (@lcsqlcmd)
END
```

Comment: If the stored procedure exists only in one database how do you expect it to run in each database? unless the stored procedure itself takes a parameter for the `Database Name` ??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to build the actual T-SQL string you want to run on each database and execute that. The other databases have no knowledge of the stored procedure you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax in your case would be something like this.

```
    CREATE TABLE #TempTable( [DBID] INT, DBName SYSNAME )
DECLARE @ForEachCommand VARCHAR( MAX ), @lcsqlcmd VARCHAR( MAX )
SET @lcsqlcmd = 'USE [?]; SELECT DB_ID() AS [DBID], DB_NAME( DB_ID()) AS DBName'
SET @ForEachCommand = 
'IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
BEGIN

            insert into #TempTable
            EXEC sp_executesql N''' + @lcsqlcmd + '''
end'
print @ForEachCommand
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb @ForEachCommand
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

See: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx

**Note:** generally it is not a good idea to build your code around undocumented procedures.

The code that does not use undocumented procedure is below:

```
    SELECT database_id, name AS DBName
INTO #Databases
FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4

CREATE TABLE #TempTable( [DBID] INT, DBName SYSNAME )

DECLARE @lcsqlcmd NVARCHAR( MAX ), @Command NVARCHAR( MAX )
SET @lcsqlcmd = 'USE [?]; SELECT DB_ID() AS [DBID], DB_NAME( DB_ID()) AS DBName'

DECLARE @DBName SYSNAME
SET @DBName = ( SELECT TOP 1 DBName FROM #Databases ORDER BY DBName )

WHILE NOT @DBName IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @Command = REPLACE( @lcsqlcmd, '?', @DBName )

    insert into #TempTable
    EXEC sp_executesql @Command

    SET @DBName = ( SELECT TOP 1 DBName FROM #Databases WHERE DBName > @DBName ORDER BY DBName )
END

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #Databases
```